# Redirect users to another page after liked a Facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a one page that contain the Facebook button like if user liked our page redirect to second page I did all things but I need to check users if they already have been liked our page immediately redirect to second page.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/example-page/" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () { 

         FB.init({appId: 'appid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
         FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1500 });


         FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
             function (response) {

                window.location = "http://www.example.net/";


             }
         );
        };


        (function () {

         var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
         e.src = document.location.protocol +
             '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

        }());



    </script>
```

Comment: You are not allowed to do that ... Facebook does not want you to treat users differently in any way based on whether they liked stuff, or not.

Comment: Facebook generator some code I found this button on first page I can't retrieve the title attribute value pro grammatically check it if the title attribute is equal to unlike  then redirect to the second page.
`<button type="submit" class="inlineBlock _2tga active _49ve" title="Unlike" id="u_0_2">`

Comment: It doesn’t matter what you found where ... you are simply not allowed to do this. _“I can't retrieve the title attribute value pro grammatically”_ - of course you can’t, because that button renders inside an iframe from a different domain, so you do not have JavaScript access it, keyword Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @CBroe I have no idea about that you mentioned thank you.